# Spring - @Async not working when the component is manually created

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I'm using the `@Async` annotation on a component that I manually instantiate in another class using the `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` :

```
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
factory.autowireBean(object);
factory.initializeBean(object, "MyObject");
```

My issue is that the class calling the asynchronous method on `object` is manually creating the Spring context and it means I cannot autowire `object` in it, and the `@Async` annotation doesn't seem to work in this case.

Here's my spring context instantiation :

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@ComponentScan({ "com.package.my" })
public class Application {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Application() {
        if (applicationContext == null) {
            applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        }
    }

}
```

I solved the issue by using a `Proxy` class that has my object autowired in it since `@Autowired` is working fine when using the `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`.

That said, I'm not really satisfied with this solution as it requires me to create an intermediate class that has no other use, and I'm pretty sure it's possible to make the `@Async` annotation work when manually creating the object.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Capture and use the return value of `initializeBean`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have no choice, my application is used as a library for another application that is not a spring application.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it is indeed working, thanks. I let you post an answer so that you can get credit for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really don't have a choice and can't declare or retrieve the bean from the `ApplicationContext`, then you can ask the `ApplicationContext` to prepare your object as if it was a bean.

The `initializeBean` method you were using actually returns a value that is meant to be the Spring processed version of itself. For example, if Spring applies its own proxying on top of the object, it would return the proxy. The [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/) states

> **Returns**: the bean instance to use, either the original or a wrapped one

So capture its return value and use that

```
object = factory.initializeBean(object, "MyObject");
```