# Best way to dynamically resolve dependencies in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I have this code structure:

```
public class NotificationService {
     public void send(Notification notification) {
         // call other services and send the notification
     }
}

public class OrderNotification implements Notification {

    @Autowired
    public TranslationService translationService;

    private String orderNumber;

    public OrderNotification(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return translationService.trans('notification.order', new Object[]{orderNumber});
    }
}
```

So, my goal is to use the `NotificationService` in this way:

```
notificationService.send(new OrderNotification(orderNumber));
```

But I know that code above won't work, because of the `translationService` won't be resolved.

My goal is to pass custom parameters to my `Notification` classes and being able to use services inside that class. What is the best way to do it in the Spring?

Comment: Take a look at this answer to see how you can initialize the `Autowired` fields on a manually created object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37463747/3876196

Comment: @AntoineB I've seen it. Is it considered as a good practice in the Spring?

Comment: Since it is the only way to do it, I believe so yes.

Comment: check also that one https://stackoverflow.com/a/6739606/8049667

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that below is not the correct answer to your question. It is however a bad design pattern to combine `Entities` and `Services`. An `Entity` should only contain information about the object and not business logic. A `Service` contains all the business logic.

You need to separate your `Service` from your `Entity`.

OrderNotification looks like a regular entity. The entity should not contain business logic. You need a specific service for the business logic.

```
public class OrderNotification implements Notification {

    private String orderNumber;

    public OrderNotification(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Order number: " + orderNumber;
    }

    //Getter & Setters
    ...
} 

@Service
public class NotificationService {

    @Autowired
    public TranslationService translationService;

    public void send(Notification notification) {
        //I do not know what trans accepts, so I assume it can accept Notification
        translationService.trans(notification.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**If you really need to combine the entity and service - Then I recommend this approach:**

```
@Service
public class Master{

    @Autowired
    NotificationService notificationService

    public void testMethod(){
        Notification notification = notificationService.createOrder("order1");
        notificationService.send(notification);
    }

}

@Service
public class NotificationService {

    @Autowired
    public TranslationService translationService;

    public Notification createOrder(String orderNumber){
        return new OrderNotification(orderNumber, translationService);
    }

    public void send(Notification notification) {
        // call other services and send the notification
        notification.getMessage();
    }
}


public class OrderNotification implements Notification {

    private TranslationService translationService;

    private String orderNumber;

    //I have changed this constructor to accept TranslationService.
    public OrderNotification(String orderNumber, TranslationService translationService) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
        this.translationService = translationService;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return translationService.trans('notification.order', new Object[]{orderNumber});
    }
}
```

Comment: Fully agree. It shouldn't be used in this way. `OrderNotification` class should be POJO in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options available:

1. Configure AOP and load time weaving to process Spring annotations on objects created with `new` keyword. This is explained in the docs [5.8.1. Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-atconfigurable).
2. Declare `OrderNotification` as a prototype scoped bean and obtain each instance from the context using [`BeanFactory.getBean(Class<T> requiredType, Object... args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) method.

   ```
   String orderNumber = "123";
   OrderNotificaton = factory.getBean(OrderNotificaton.class, orderNumber);
   ```
3. Drop the `@Autowired` and use plain constructor injection.

   ```
   public OrderNotification(TranslationService translationService, String orderNumber) {
       this.translationService = Objects.requireNonNull(translationService);
       this.orderNumber = Objects.requireNonNull(orderNumber);
   }
   ```

If you only require simple `@Autowired` I'd go with option 3. It's the simplest approach and makes writing unit tests easier as you don't have to depend on Spring.

Comment: the 3 option looks good, but it's very annoying to inject `TranlationService` into each class where I want to use notification.